# Sql Server - is it safe to convert to Uniquidentifier from newid()?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, uniqueidentifier

I have set newid() to many tables as primary key, which is also refereed as foreign key at various places.

is it safe to convert nweid() to uniqueidentifier?

is there any chances of datalost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually convert, `NEWID()` returns an `uniqueidentifier`:

> NEWID (Transact-SQL)
>
> Creates a unique value of type uniqueidentifier.

A separate note, though: Be wary of using `uniqueidentifier`s as primary keys if you do not have a separate clustered index. Since uniqueidentifiers are not sequential, your inserts will have worse performance than if using a sequentially incrementing key.

Comment: Right, which is why Microsoft introduced [`newsequentialid()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) for use as a primary key

Comment: as a default value i have newid(), if i will change column type varchar(36) to uniqueidentifier and default value newsequentialid(). does any data lost? I want to change datatype as i have read somewhere taht newid() creates more fragmentation than newsequentialid()

Comment: @Andomar: Interesting, didn't know about that function! Although this remark seems to diminsh the usefulness: "Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer __since Windows was started__. After restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range". Even though I don't often restart my database servers, as soon as I do it the first time, performance would drop again, I would think?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to convert newid () to uniqueidentifier because IT ALREADY IS ONE. So there is no conversion.

If you read the documentation:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

it says:

Return Types
uniqueidentifier